# RDLC Rendering System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, rdlc, reportviewer

I'm trying to Export in Excel automatically my generated reports using RDLC rendering. the code below was inside of a timer, the timer will check if there's request on the database, it will get only 1 requested report from the database.
I repeated the process many times(I think 10 times before error occurred.) but LocalProcessingException occurred with inner exception System.OutOfMemoryException(see codes below). I use GC.Collect but it doesn't help.

```
try
{
    using (ReportViewer ReportViewerControl = new ReportViewer())
    {
        ReportViewerControl.LocalReport.ReportPath = "myrdlcpath";
        ReportViewerControl.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportViewerControl.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ReportSource);
        ReportViewerControl.LocalReport.DisplayName = "mydisplayname";
        ReportViewerControl.LocalReport.SetParameters(MyReportParameters);
        ReportViewerControl.LocalReport.Refresh();

        File.WriteAllBytes(
            "MyreportFileName.xlsx",
            ReportViewerControl.LocalReport.Render( //LocalProcessingException here having inner exception System.OutOfMemoryException
                "EXCELOPENXML",
                null,
                out mimeType,
                out encoding,
                out extension,
                out streamids,
                out warnings));

        ReportViewerControl.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportViewerControl.Clear();
}
}
catch(LocalProcessingException ex)
{
    GC.Collect();
    using (ReportViewer ReportViewerControl = new ReportViewer())
    {
        ReportViewerControl.LocalReport.ReportPath = "myrdlcpath";
        ReportViewerControl.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportViewerControl.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ReportSource);
        ReportViewerControl.LocalReport.DisplayName = "mydisplayname";
        ReportViewerControl.LocalReport.SetParameters(MyReportParameters);
        ReportViewerControl.LocalReport.Refresh();

        File.WriteAllBytes(
            "MyreportFileName.xlsx",
            ReportViewerControl.LocalReport.Render(
                "EXCELOPENXML",
                null,
                out mimeType,
                out encoding,
                out extension,
                out streamids,
                out warnings));

        ReportViewerControl.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportViewerControl.Clear();
    }
}
ReportSource.Value = null;
```